# spring-security-saml2-core:1.0.3.BUILD-SNAPSHOT is not found in the repo https://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am trying to upgrade to Spring 5. I want to upgrade to spring Security 5 too.

Spring security 5 upgrade causes [issue with Spring Saml2](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-saml/issues/211).

This issue of class not found error is solved in the PR which is merged.

The snapshot, 1.0.3.BUILD-SNAPSHOT is not there in the [specified repo](https://projects.spring.io/spring-security-saml/).

```
Warning:project ':api': Web Facets/Artifacts will not be configured properly
Details: org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolveException: Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':api:runtimeClasspath'.
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionNotFoundException: 
Could not find org.springframework.security.extensions:spring-security-saml2-core:1.0.3.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.
Required by:
    project :api
    project :api > project :common
    project :api > project :core
```

Help me with finding the snapshot in the spring repo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is solved in the December release [1.0.3.RELEASE](https://projects.spring.io/spring-security-saml/) of Spring security Saml.